# KnockoutJs Anchor tag binding with additional HTML

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

in Html I have the following

```
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">My Company<b class="caret"></b></a>
```

which produces a link, with a caret at the end.

Using knockoutJS, with this,

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-bind="attr: { title: someTextBinding }, text: someTextBinding"><b class="caret"></b></a>
```

How do I keep the carat on the screen? I'v tried using a computed, but the caret gets sent in as text?

Comment: That isn't pure html. What library are you using? I'm guessing Bootstrap?

Comment: @Jason yes, sorry I should have mentioed that. Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [containerless syntax for `text` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html#note-3-using-text-without-a-container-element) like this:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-bind="attr: { title: someTextBinding }">
  <!--ko text: someTextBinding-->
  <!--/ko-->
  <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

> The `<!--ko-->` and `<!--/ko-->` comments act as start/end markers, defining a “virtual element” that contains the markup inside. Knockout understands this virtual element syntax and binds as if you had a real container element.

Comment: I had found this to work
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-bind="html: someComputedValue"></a>
But I like your solution much much better. Thank you

Comment: Yes. Works like a champ.